# How use curl with spaces in json

Tags: json, powershell, curl, post

When making a POST call with curl I'm having trouble getting the JSON data to be passed correctly. The string is cut off at the first whitespace/blank space.

My call looks like this, I'm executing through a powershell script that has two parameters. Using these parameters I concatenate the JSON that is used for the call.

I input for instance `854e-ae7686fbc75a 365` as parameters

```
# usage: powershell -file send.ps1 [apitoken] [interval]

param (
    [string]$apitoken = "",
    [int]$startInterval = "365"
)

$AUTHORIZATION = $apitoken
$STARTDATE = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$startInterval)
$ENDDATE = (Get-Date)
$JSON = '{\"ApiToken\":\"' + $AUTHORIZATION + '\",' +
    '\"StartDate\":\"' + $STARTDATE + '\",' +
    '\"EndDate\":\"' + $ENDDATE + '\",' +
    '\"Type\":\"SalesExport\"' +
    '}'

$CURLEXE = '..\bin\curl.exe'
$CurlArgument = '-X', 'POST',
                '-m', 7200,
                '-H', '"Content-Type:application/json"',
                '-d', $JSON,
                'https://my.server/export/sales'

& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument
```

The `STARTDATE` would then be the current date minus 365 days. `ENDDATE` would be the current date.

The problem is as soon as there is a blank space (or possibly any whitespace) in the JSON variable curl thinks that the JSON has ended and says that the JSON is unterminated. There is no difference if I surround the variable with single or double quotes.

Even if the whitespace is inside one of the two DateTime variables the problem occurs!

How can I format the JSON properly so that it can include whitespace?

Comment: I've found a partial solution in that if I make sure there are no whitespace in the JSON and use `(Get-Date).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` the code works. But in the case I in the future would need the time string also this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but since you're using PowerShell anyway: why not use the native `Invoke-WebRequest` instead of an external command?

```
$today   = (Get-Date).Date
$uri     = 'https://example.org/export/sales'
$headers = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}
$data    = @{
    'ApiToken'  = $apitoken
    'StartDate' = $today.AddDays(-$startInterval).ToString('d')
    'EndDate'   = $today.ToString('d')
    'Type'      = 'SalesExport'
} | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $data -Uri $uri
```

Alternatively you can define the JSON data as a multiline string:

```
$startDate = $today.AddDays(-$startInterval).ToString('d')
$endDate   = $today.ToString('d')
$data = @"
{
    "ApiToken": "$apitoken",
    "StartDate": "$startDate",
    "EndDate": "$endDate",
    "Type": "SalesExport"
}
"@
```

Comment: I tried it but got the following error message: Invoke-WebRequest : `"Invalid JSON primitive: Type."`

Comment: Still no luck.
`Invoke-WebRequest : "Invalid JSON primitive: Type."
At line:33 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $data -Uri $ur ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`

Comment: My bad. `$data` must be a JSON string, not a hashtable. See updated answer.